# Golang. How to create loop function using html/template package

Tags: templates, go

I'm trying to implement loop as custom function. It takes number of iterations and content between curly brackets, then it should iterate content between brackets n times. Please, see example:

**main.go**

```
template.Must(template.ParseFiles("palette.html")).Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "loop": func(n int, content string) string {
            var r string
            for i := 0; i <= n; i++ {
                r += content
            }
            return r
        },
    }).ExecuteTemplate(rw, index, nil)
```

**index.html**

```
{{define "index"}}
<div class="row -flex palette">
  {{loop 16}}
    <div class="col-2"></div>
  {{end}}
</div>
{{end}}
```

**Output**

```
<div class="row -flex palette">
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    ... 16 times
</div>
```

Is it possible to implement it? The motivation is that standard functionality of the `text/template` doesn't allow just to iterate content between curly bracket. Yes we can do it by `range` action going through "outside" data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `range` on a function that returns a slice. http://play.golang.org/p/FCuLkEHaZn

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    html := `
<div class="row -flex palette">
  {{range loop 16}}
    <div class="col-2"></div>
  {{end}}
</div>`
    tmpl := template.Must(template.New("test").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "loop": func(n int) []struct{} {
            return make([]struct{}, n)
        },
    }).Parse(html))
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
}
```

Comment: Good idea! Thus there is no way to get content from curly brackets?)

Comment: If you aren't using the slice elements, it is more efficient to use an empty struct. http://play.golang.org/p/_jRV62bOB3 This way you only allocate a slice header (constant size) instead of n elements.

Comment: yeap! you are absolutely right!) @Innominate, please update your answer.